# Using vertical multiline braces to denote difference as opposed to grouping

Tags: multirow, braces

I would like to have several lines with vertical braces next to them. However, those braces should not group the lines, as can be done with the `cases` environment. Instead, I'd like the braces to start and end in the middle of two subsequent lines in order to talk about some differences between them.

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Should these lines be in a tabular environment, or a list? What would be the context?

Comment: It honestly does not matter. There will nothing else be going on, so either is fine. Do you need more context besides that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found TikZ to be rather helpful. Below is a MWE of what I ended up using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-0.1\baselineskip]

\node (l1) {Line 1};
\node[below=of l1] (l2) {Line 2};
\node[below=of l2] (l3) {Line 3};
\node[below=of l3] (l4) {Line 4};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace, mirror}] (l1.west) -- (l2.west) node [midway,left] {\(\alpha\)};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace, mirror}] (l2.west) -- (l3.west) node [midway,left] {\(\beta\)};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace, mirror}] (l3.west) -- (l4.west) node [midway,left] {\(\gamma\)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This renders to:

[image: Rendering of above code]

Close enough, and less hacky.

Answer (score 3):

this is a hack, and a rather ridiculous one at that, but it was fun.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\hspace*{2em}Line 1\\
\smash{\makebox[2em]{\hfil\raisebox{.6\baselineskip}{$\alpha\,\big\{$}}}%
Line 2\\
\smash{\makebox[2em]{\hfil\raisebox{.6\baselineskip}{$\beta\,\big\{$}}}%
Line 3\\
\smash{\makebox[2em]{\hfil\raisebox{.6\baselineskip}{$\gamma\,\big\{$}}}%
Line 4

\end{document}
```

[image]